# BOFH Gravatar Week - Let's keep going!

Tags: discussion, gravatar

This is your chance to show your true colours...

Use the (semi-) official Bastard Operator From Hell Gravatar for a week or a while.  [I don't think there's any particular reason, it just seemed like a good idea.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4900388#4900388)

**UPDATE:** Why stop now!  This deserves at least one more week.

[image: BOFH Logo]

Comment: Yes, yes... it's all Iain's fault!

Comment: Meh, I was never that taken by BOFH week as it was. I've reverted back to my normal kitty. Sorry!

Comment: @MarkHenderson Punishment will be swift and brutal.

Comment: Another week? Hell, I'm keeping it permanently.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

And this one:

[image: votes]

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried turning it off and on again?

[image: BOFH]

Answer (score 9):

Pirates can be bastards too!

[image]

Except this one is better:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Honey Devil:

[image]

But aren't cats already BOFHs?

Comment: Cats are the role models for BOsFH.

Answer (score 6):

Modifications are allowed, e.g.

DOFH (Derpy Operator From Hell):

[image: DOFH]

Badass Operator From Hell:

[image: ewwhite bofh]

I wanted to see what other colours look like, so ZOFH:

[image]

***STOP MAKING THINGS OVERLAP I CAN'T HANDLE OVERLAPPING THINGS THEY CANNOT OVERLAP DON'T MAKE THEM OVERLAP YOU CAN'T OVERLAP THINGS OVERLAPPING ISN'T OKAY!!!!!!***

--Wesley

[image]

Comment: *Phew!* I'm lucky you didn't notice the fringe of reddishness I left on my ZOFH!

Answer (score 6):

Here are some others, ready to go...  [Many more available around here,](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4902257#4902257) courtesy of Kitteh from Hell.

VOFH (FH is redundant, I think)

[image: voretaq7]

ALSO:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image: It works for me... (plugs UPS back in)]

My favorite BOFH quote.

Comment: "WHAT?! You've been reading forbidden literature as well?"  -- http://bofh.ntk.net/BOFH/1995/bastard95-08.php

Answer (score 6):

[Evan's](https://serverfault.com/users/7200/evan-anderson) is awesome!

[image: infinite bofh]

I didn't want to add another answer, so I thought I'd just add the equally [awesome ZOFH](https://serverfault.com/users/984/zoredache) to this one.  I love the clean, higher-quality image than some of us used, and it's neatly radiused corners.  But WTF is that line on the bottom?

[image: zofh]

Comment: What can I say-- fractals make me happy!  Thanks for the shout out. It was really time to drop the Choppertar. Now I just need to come up with one before BOFH "week" ends.

Answer (score 5):

@WesleyDavid finally got mine right.:)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Can I be one of the cool kids too?

[image: Hyppy BOFH]

Answer (score 4):

Done and done. Well done. And by well done, I mean well played.

[image: BOFH]

Answer (score 4):

Done :-)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Someone else joined the party

[image: SvenW]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

And here's mine

Comment: Expect to be chewed out for not getting transparency and overlap perfect!

Comment: I like it like that more, as it looks like a dial :)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Comment: Get your own idiom!

Answer (score 1):

[image: I'll play along :)]