# Why do some user pictures feature a red phone?

Tags: discussion, gravatar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [BOFH Gravatar Week - Let's keep going!](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3368/bofh-gravatar-week-lets-keep-going)

I noticed that some users have a red phone with horns superimposed on their original picture.

Does that signify that the user is bad for some reason?

Answer (score 7):

[My god we're all bastards!](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3368/bofh-gravatar-week-lets-keep-going) -- Just one of our irregularly unscheduled memes.  I suppose I should log in to gravatar and change back to my normal photo though...